# AS3 - iOS - can the language setting of the user be detected?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

Does anybody know how to do this?
Detect the language of the user's iPhone in actionscript 3.

Alternatively I have a language selection screen currently programmed, I will probably leave it at that.

If anyone has any good links or resources for as3 iOS development, please post :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Capabilities.language` or `Capabilities.languages` ?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#languages

If it doesn't work you could use `native extentions` (should be realy easy) : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html